# Error - Missing return in function expected to return 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown]

    }
```

// this line has the error - missing return in function expected to return 'UIInterfaceOrintationMask'
}

```
func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
      }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
```

case too. You can use this:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown]
    } else { // I guess this means your userInterfaceIdiom is equal to .Pad
        return [] // here you should return UIInterfaceOrientationMasks you may want to use for Pad devices.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `supportedInterfaceOrientations` only returns the correct type if `UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone`. It needs to return a result in the `else` clause of that `if` too.